# The process could not execute 'sp_replcmds' on 'S15415940'. Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "dbo" does not exist

Tags: replication

Can anyone show me the way to fix these error messages:

> The process could not execute 'sp_replcmds' on 'S15415940'. (Source:
>   MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL20011)
>
> Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "dbo"
>   does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you
>   do not have permission. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 15517)
>
> The process could not execute 'sp_replcmds' on 'S15415940'. (Source:
>   MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL22037)

Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

In my experience I had this message

> The process could not execute 'sp_replcmds'

when two log reader processes where accidently trying to run.

The fix I had was to:
 connect at the publisher, look in master..sysprocesses for a a leftover process from the distributor
 kill it, and relaunch the log reader on the distributor.